# Cannot open modal with 'keydown'

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

I have an encoded actionlink which on click will open a modal pop up.  In order to make my application accessible, I need to be able to open the modal with a key press (spacebar) also.  The on click works fine but the key press doesn't.  Please help.

Encoded actionlink:

```
@Html.EncodedActionLink(
    "Preview", 
    "Preview", 
    "Forms", 
    new { 
        stagingId = Model.FormData.StagingNotificationId 
    },
    new { 
        @class = "'modal-link btn btn-success'", 
        id = "decSave" 
    })
```

On click code that works with mouse:

```
 $(function() {
     $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
         $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
     });
 });
```

On key down code (hits the alert but does not open modal):

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('keydown', '.modal-link', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32) {

            alert('test')

            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
            $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because click event propagates and triggers the modal click where as keydown doesn't do that.

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('keydown', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 32) {
            $(this).trigger("click")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @JohnNewbie I would request you to accept the answer if it helped you.